# Python installer blocked at initializing step

Tags: python, installation

I was trying to install Python3.6 on my computer using the installer, but the installer blocked at the initializing step. I wonder why would this happen.

I tried Python2.7 as well but it also blocked at the same place.

It blocked here:

[image: The place it blocked at]

Comment: It's really hard to help you troubleshoot the problem without more details. Have you checked your system logs and monitored your processes? Alternatively, try a different install mechanism, such as via the command line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Untick the option to install for all users ... that sorted it for me :)

Comment: Rebooting and installing again worked for me (without needing to uncheck the mentioned option)

Answer (score 0):

Just now, I had the same problem, and when I checked the taskbar, there was a request from the Python Installer to Run the program as administrator, accept the request and the installer continues the process :)