# Python 2.7.16 Installation stuck

Tags: windows, python-2.7, installation

I am trying to install Python 2.7.16(64-bit) in my laptop having windows 10 home edition, and it is stuck at 'Publishing product information' stage.

I tried to kill the process and start once again, but it stops at the same stage. How to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: laptop RAM and hard disk size

Comment: 16 GB & 500 GB hard disk

Comment: does your user account name have space(s)?

Comment: did u install for all users?
[Python installer blocked at initializing step](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47764527)